# How to load html head tags from one source

Tags: tags, loading, head

Okay, for static pages. Is there a way to load everything between the head tags (css,javascript,etc) from one source so we don't have to load it in every html file? I know this may be a stupid question but I couldn't find one on here and if there was already a post about it, I guess I was stupid to miss it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you environment permits you can use Server Side Includes http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html which doesnt really involve using traditional dynamic scripting languages or servlet technology. In any case the HTML standard also allows you reference external CSS and JS - they dont have to be inline. If they are at the same URL they will only get loaded once by the browser.